# How to find the basis of $\textsf V$ and for $\textsf{V}^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

> Let  $\textsf{V}=\left\{
> \begin{pmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4 \end{pmatrix}
> \in \mathbb{R}^4 :\, x_1=x_3+x_4 \textrm{ and } x_2=x_3-x_4 \right\}$. Find  a basis  for $\textsf V$  and for $\textsf{V}^\perp$.

*My attempt* :  A basis for $\textsf V$ will be $(1, 0,-1 ,-1)$  and $(0,1,-1,1)$.
And we know that $\dim (\textsf{V}^{\perp}) = \dim (\mathbb{R}^4) - \dim (\textsf V)= 4-2 =2$.

But I don't know  how  we can find the  basis of $\textsf{V}^{\perp}$.

Comment: Have you seen the Gram-Schmidt process?

Comment: ya  @LuizCordeiro but  my  question is not  asking about Gram - schmidt

Comment: Why don't you apply Gram-Schmidt? You have seen it for a reason, you know...

Comment: How is $(1,0,-1,-1)$ in $V$?

Comment: @LuizCordeiro i don't how to  apply here

Comment: @PinkPanther  $x_1  - x_ 3 - x_ 4 = 0$ given condition

Comment: that's not true, $1+1+1=3$ if I am not mistaken

Comment: As @PinkPanther's mentioned, first fix your basis for $V$ (you want $x_1=-2$ in the first vector). Apply Gram-Schmidt to find an **orthogonal** basis of $V$. Now take a vector $e_1$ of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Use Gram-Schmidt again to find the projection $p_V(e)$ of $e$ onto $V$. The vector $f_1=e_1-p_V(e_1)$ will be in the orthogonal $V^\perp$, and with some luck it will be nonzero. (cont.)

Comment: Repeat this procedure with another vector $e_2$ of the canonical basis. With some luck, $f_2=e_2-p_V(e_2)$ will be LI with $e_1$. If not, try another vector of the canonical basis. As soon as you find two LI ones in $V^\perp$, you're done.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro That seems like far too much work when one can read a basis for $V^\perp$ directly from the defining equations of $V$.

Comment: Actually, what you’ve found is a basis for $V^\perp$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll do a similar one for you: Take the space $W=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4):x_1=3x_3, x_2=0, x_1=3x_4\right\}$.

Let us find a basis of $W^\perp$.

First, find a basis for $W$: The sole vector $w=(3,0,1,1)$ works. Note that $\langle w,w\rangle=3^2+0^2+1^2+1^2=11$

Now consider the first vector $e_1=(1,0,0,0)$ of the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$. The projection onto $W$ is
$$p_W(e_1)=\frac{\langle e_1,w\rangle}{\langle w,w\rangle}w=\frac{3}{11}w$$
so the following vector is in $W^\perp$:
\begin{align*}
f_1&=e_1-p_W(e_1)\\
&=(1,0,0,0)-\frac{3}{11}\left(3,0,1,1\right)\\
&=(1,0,0,0)-\left(\frac{9}{11},0,\frac{3}{11},\frac{3}{11}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac{2}{11},0,-\frac{3}{11},-\frac{3}{11}\right)
\end{align*}

Let's do the same for $e_2=(0,1,0,0)$:
$$p_W(e_2)=\frac{0}{11}w=0$$
so I was lucky: $f_2=e_2-p_W(e_2)=e_2$ is in $W^\perp$.

Again, with $e_3=(0,0,1,0)$: $p_W(e_3)=\frac{1}{11}w$, so

$$f_3=e_3-\frac{1}{11}w=\left(-\frac{3}{11},0,\frac{10}{11},-\frac{1}{11},\right)$$

I'll leave it to you to verify that $\left\{f_1,f_2,f_3\right\}$ is LI, so it is a basis of $W^\perp$ (which has dimension $4-\dim W=4-1=3$).

Answer (score 1):

Note that $V= \{ (x_3+x_4, x_3-x_4,x_3,x_4)^T \}$ and since
$(x_3+x_4, x_3-x_4,x_3,x_4)^T = x_3(1,1,1,0)^T + x_4(1,-1,0,1)^T $, we see that
$v_1=(1,1,1,0)^T, v_2=(1,-1,0,1)^T$ spans $V$ and it is easy to check that they are linearly independent hence $V$ is a basis for $V$.

To compute a basis for $V^\bot$, we can start with $v_1,v_2,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$ and apply Gram Schmidt (ignoring the zero vectors that will result). This will produce an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$, and the first two will span $V$ and so the last two (non zero) will span $V^\bot$. (Actually, since $v_1 \bot v_2$, the process will just normalise $v_1,v_2$).

Alternatively, we can 'eyeball' $v_1,v_2$ and try to find two linearly independent
vectors that are orthogonal to $v_1,v_2$. One pair is
$(1,0,-1,-1)^T, (0,1,-1,1)^T$.

Comment: Or, just read a basis for $V^\perp$ from the defining equations of $V$.

Comment: I guess that would be 'eyeballing'?

Comment: Aye, but eyeballing the equations rather than the basis of $V$.

Comment: I guess we are dualing now...

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x_1 = x_3 + x_4$ if and only if $x_1 - x_3 - x_4 = 0$, which is equivalent to $\langle x, (1, 0, -1, -1) \rangle = 0$.  Similarly, $x_2 = x_3 - x_4$ if and only if $\langle x, (0, 1, -1, 1) \rangle = 0$.  Therefore, $V$ is the set of vectors which are orthogonal to both $(1, 0, -1, -1)$ and $(0, 1, -1, 1)$.

Thus, if we set $W := \operatorname{span} \{ (1, 0, -1, -1), (0, 1, -1, 1) \}$, this implies that $V = W^\perp$, and therefore $V^\perp = (W^\perp)^\perp = W$.  From here, it should be easy to find a basis for $W$.